# Opa amigos, queria saber por que no código abaixo a resposta só sai certa se antes de escrever a palavra (santo) eu der um espaço. :/

Tags: python-3.x

```
cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da sua cidade: ')).title()
p = cidade.find('Santo')
if p == True:
   print('A sua cidade começa com Santo.')
else:
   print('A sua cidade não começa com Santo.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessidade do espaço adicionado ao inicio da entrada se dá por conta do mal uso do método [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) e uma conversão de tipos desastrosa.

O método `str.find()` retorna um valor numérico inteiro(zero ou positivo) que é o índice da primeira aparição de substring, passado por parâmetro, dentro de uma string. Ou então retorna `-1` caso a string não seja encontrada.

Portanto na linha:

```
p = cidade.find('Santo')
```

A variável `p` independente do substring `'Santo'` estar ou não contido em `cidade` o resultado sempre será um objeto do tipo [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

A conversão equivocada acontece na linha:

```
if p == True:
```

Onde você compara `p` que é do tipo `int` com `True` que é uma das duas [constantes lógicas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values).
Acontece que quando há uma comparação entre instancias de classes diferentes o interpretador primeiro tenta converter o segundo operando para o mesmo tipo do primeiro de forma que possa haver uma comparação. Mas ao converter `True` em `int`...

```
>>> print(int(True))
1
```

O resultado é `1` e que torna o seu código equivalente esse:

```
cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da sua cidade: ')).title()
p = cidade.find('Santo')
if p == 1: #substituindo a constante lógica True por sua conversão numérica.
   print('A sua cidade começa com Santo.')
else:
   print('A sua cidade não começa com Santo.')
```

Ou seja a comparação só será verdadeira se o substring `'Santo'` aparecer no índice `1` da string. Lembrando que o índice do primeiro caractere de uma string é `0`.

Para corrigir basta fazer com que o código compare corretamente a posição da substring `'Santo'` e posição de interesse:

```
cidade = str(input('Digite o nome da sua cidade: ')).title()
p = cidade.find('Santo')
if p == 0: #Verifica se o substring 'Santo' aparece a partir da primeira letra.
   print('A sua cidade começa com Santo.')
else:
   print('A sua cidade não começa com Santo.')
```

Comment: obrigado pela explicação, esclareceu bastante minha dúvida!!!